# For some reason, NSPredicate is not filtering my UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, view, nspredicate, xcode4.6

For some reason NSPredicate isn't filtering my UITableView (it's supposed to be filtering my TableView by selections made in a UIPickerView). Users make their pickerview selections, press the GO button (segue is attached from Pickerview to Table View controller).

Any idea as to why it isn't working? See code below.

**ViewController.m (TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER)**

```
  - (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview
        {
            return 1;
        }

        - (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
                return [searchResults count];
            } else {
                return [Strains count];
            }
        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

            StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
                cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];

            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
                NSLog(@"Using the search results");

                cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
                cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
                cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
                cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
                cell.actionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
                cell.ingestLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

                NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Using the FULL LIST!!");

                cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
                cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
                cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
                cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
                cell.actionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
                cell.ingestLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];        
            }
            return cell;
        }


        - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
        {
            NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                            predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                            searchText];

                searchResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
            }


            -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
            shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
            {
                [se

    lf filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                                       scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                              objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                             selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
            return YES;
        }

        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            StrainDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[StrainDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StrainDetailViewController" bundle:nil]; if ([searchResults count]) {

                detailViewController.title = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
                detailViewController.strainDetail = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            } else {

                detailViewController.title = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
                detailViewController.strainDetail = [Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSLog(@"%@", Strains);
            }

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        }

- (void)PickerViewControllerDidFinish:(PickerViewController *)viewController {
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

**PickerViewController.h**

```
@protocol PickerViewControllerDelegate;

@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController {


    UIPickerView *pickerView;

    NSMutableArray *array1;
    NSMutableArray *array2;
    NSMutableArray *array3;



    NSArray *Strains;
    NSArray *searchResults;

    NSMutableData *data;



}

- (IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PickerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

- (void)populateArray1;
- (void)populateArray2;
- (void)populateArray3;




@end

@protocol PickerViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)PickerViewControllerDidFinish:(PickerViewController*)viewController;

@end
```

**PickerViewController.m**

```
@implementation PickerViewController

- (void)handleCloseButton:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(PickerViewControllerDidFinish:)]) {
        [self.delegate PickerViewControllerDidFinish:self];

    }
}

@synthesize pickerView;


    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark picker view methods
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
    {
        return 3;
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        if (component == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:row]);            
        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array2 objectAtIndex:row]);            
        }

        if (component == 2)
        {
            NSLog(@"you selected %@", [array3 objectAtIndex:row]);            
        }
    }    

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {
        if (component == 0)
        {
            return [array1 count];
        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            return [array2 count];
        }    

        if (component == 2)
        {
            return [array3 count];
        }    
        else
        {
            return [array1 count];
        }
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {        
        if (component == 0)
        {
            return [array1 objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        if (component == 1)
        {
            return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }

        if (component == 2)
        {
            return [array3 objectAtIndex:row];
        }        
        else
        {
            return [array2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }
    }

    - (void)populateArray1
    {
        array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [array1 addObject:@"Arthritis"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Cancer"];
        [array1 addObject:@"HIV"];
        [array1 addObject:@"Migraines"];
            [array1 addObject:@"Insomnia"];      
        }    

        - (void)populateArray2
        {
            array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            [array2 addObject:@"Nausea"];
            [array2 addObject:@"Pain"];
            [array2 addObject:@"Appetite"];
            [array2 addObject:@"Fever"];
                [array2 addObject:@"Exhaustion"];        
            }

            - (void)populateArray3
            {
                array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                [array3 addObject:@"Oil"];
                [array3 addObject:@"Plant"];
                [array3 addObject:@"Edible"];
                [array3 addObject:@"Powder"];


             }

         - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pickerGo"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ViewController *strainTableView = [(UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];

        NSPredicate *ailmentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ailment contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

        NSPredicate *actionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Action contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];

        NSPredicate *ingestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ingestion contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];


        NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ailmentPredicate,actionPredicate,ingestPredicate, nil]];

        searchResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [strainTableView setSearchResults: searchResults];
    }
}
```

Comment: i guess your filter array becomes empty after filtering, just check value of `searchResults` in your filtering method, hope you will get to the problem, Good Luck

Comment: searchResults was originally for the searchbar that's attached to my uitableview. Should I change "searchResults" for the filtered Picker results? I'm totally confused by this issue; lol.

Comment: yes, you can display result in same `UITableview` just manage flag to identify which data to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",  searchText];

searchResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Looks to be trying to use "Strain" objects (which you haven't given a definition of but which are definitely compound objects) as string objects.

CONTAINS[cd] is a string comparison function.

Define your predicate more like the compound version you're using for the picker.

Comment: I'm confused?  I thought Strains was defined in ViewController.m? What do you mean by "Define your predicate more like the compound version"?

Comment: You have a NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate used by the picker. This is the correct way to do the filtering as it uses the contents of the objects. For the table view your trying to use a single predicate and that won't work.

Comment: Ohh I see what you're saying! Okay, so I've changed the predicate on my tableview to look like this: - (void)filterContentForPicker:(NSString*)searchText
{
  
    NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ailmentPredicate,actionPredicate,ingestPredicate, nil]];
    
    searchResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    
} But it's saying ailmentPredicate and actionPredicate are undefined? Am I missing something super elementary here? Lol. Thank you!

Comment: The picker has 3 components by the looks of it, so where does the single 'searchText' come from. The picker predicate is made up of parts for each component: NSPredicate *ailmentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:...];
NSPredicate *actionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:...];
NSPredicate *ingestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:...];
NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ailmentPredicate,actionPredicate,ingestPredicate, nil]];

Comment: Okay, so now (for example), I have this:  NSPredicate *ingestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ingestion contains[cd] %@", [UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
    
    NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ailmentPredicate,actionPredicate,ingestPredicate, nil]];
 Only showing you the one component as comments won't let me paste all of the code, lol. But it says 'No known class method for selector 'SelectedRowinComponent'.

Comment: Should I not include "SelectedRowInComponent" as it's already coded onto PickerViewController.m?

Comment: Your question says you have a segue from the picker to the table view. So you need to collect the chosen picker values and pass them to the table controller during the segue.

Comment: Ahhh that would be what I'm missing, lol :) For the segue, I simply connected it via StoryBoards. Would I have to do the segue programatically, or is there a way for me to pass the values during the already occuring Segue X? Thanks so much for your help; you're a life saver!

Comment: In the picker controller, implement - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender. In this method you have access to both the picker and the table controller (via segue. destinationViewController)

Comment: Ok! Almost there :) Following an example. See my updated PickerViewController.m above. My only question: What do I do with [vc setMyObjectHere:object]; ? In other words, what do I replace "object" with? Thus far, I assume that code is telling PickerViewController.m to pass selected values during the segue. Does that look right?

Comment: ViewController *vc, needs to be replaced by your table controller class. You need to decide what you want to pass, probably the filtered list is best (the searchResults you calculate using the predicate in the code above). Then you can do [vc setSearchResults: searchResults];

Comment: ViewController is the name of the view that contains my uitableview. SO, now I have this: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pickerGo"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ViewController *strainTableView = [segue destinationViewController];
        
        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [strainTableView setSearchResults: searchResults];

Comment: (That last bit is posted in PickerViewController.m). And I still have the error in my ViewController.m. Am I getting my Table View controller class wrong?

Comment: OR, if I use: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pickerGo"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        UITableViewController *ViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        
        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [UITableViewController setSearchResults: searchResults];
        
I simply get the error, "No known class method for selector setSearchResults".

Comment: ViewController is the correct class to use then. Add NSLog statements to ensure the segue method is being called and that the ViewController is given the searchResults. The ViewController should be using the searchResults to populate the table view (which it already was for searchResultsTableView).

Comment: Amazing. Okay, PickerViewController.m is now officially error free (lol, see updated segue code above). My only issue now is that in my viewcontroller.m (tableviewcontroller) where I have this code:  NSPredicate *ailmentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ailment contains[cd] %@", [UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]; It's telling me, "No known class method for selector, 'selectedRowInComponent". If I remove that selectedRowInComponent, running the app throws me an error.

Comment: Now that you're passing searchResults to ViewController you have no reason to use a predicate or try to use the picker view (that you have no access to). Use searchResults for everything you need and remove any references to a picker. The picker is entirely handled in the other controller and then you pass the result to ViewController.

Comment: Oh no way. Wicked :) Ok, so I removed any reference of the picker from viewcontroller.m (see updated code above as well). Now when I run the app, the console throws me this: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setSearchResults:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85493d0'

Comment: Ok, so the segue preparation code is wrong - because your ViewController is wrapped inside a navigation controller. Change to ViewController *strainTableView = [(UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];

Comment: Weirdest, problem, ever. Changed it (see code above) exactly like you said. I run the app, and no error, but it doesn't filter the tableview. Just gives me the full list? Lol!

Comment: Still no filtering (assuming you only altered the code/bottom part of pickerviewcontroller.m).

Comment: I changed the segue preparation (showed the searchResults being set before being filtered) and added logging in the ViewController so you can see wether it's using the filtered list or the full list.

Comment: HA HA! Yep, ran the app, and console says (in bold, aggressive capital letters), "Using the  FULL LIST!!"

Comment: :-) So now you just need to get your 2 table view references sorted out and we can draw the longest comment conversation in the history of the world to an end and I can sleep easy.

Comment: LOL!! Okay, so put me out of my misery here, because this is going to be the thing that keeps me awake tonight counting the dots on my ceiling. -Why- is it using the full list when CLEARLY I'm telling it to filter based on selections made in the PickerView? How do I fix this? O_O (that's my eyes starting to bug out after hours of staring at code).

Comment: It decides what to do not based on the data you give it but on the table view. How do you configure self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView? Do you really even want 2 different table views in ViewController or does it only ever display search results?

Comment: The only reason for the 2 table views in the first place is because it generally displays a full list of items. The second tableview is because it has a search bar attached to it (it displays the results, should users want to search the full list for specific items). So currently viewcontroller is managing the tableview when it isn't being searched, and when it is being used by the searchbar.